# Using datetime and getting "<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f1463aeec80>"

Tags: python, datetime

I am coding a web scraper and and my code keeps printing <generator object  at 0x7f1463aeec80>

```
dates_with_monthname = re.findall(
    r'((?:January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)\s\d{1,2})',
    str(text)
)
```

```
while i<len(dates_with_monthname):

  i=i+1


Date_List = (datetime.datetime.strptime(i, "%B-%d") for i in dates_with_monthname)


print(Date_List)
```

I am having a hard time understanding why it prints out <generator object  at 0x7f1463aeec80>

Haven't tried much because I am very confused as to why it would print that.

Comment: Because you have used a generator expression in the line before.

Answer (score 0):

try appending
print(list(Date_List))